# Problema en Select de fechas y montos

Tags: php, mysql

Chicos tengo un problema que no he logrado solucionar

esta es mi consulta a la bd

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%c' ) AS fecha, SUM( COALESCE( grand_total, 0 )) as total FROM sma_sales WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') = '2018' AND customer_id = 10 OR customer_id = 21 OR customer_id = 23 OR customer_id = 30 OR customer_id = 37 GROUP BY date_format( date, '%c' ) ORDER BY date_format( date, '%c' ) ASC
```

pero me arroja datos erroneos, al realizar la misma consulta con los IDs por separado el monto es correcto, pero al tomar toda la data junta se vuelve loco el monto que da al final

el total por usuario haciendo la consulta de uno en uno de los ids para Noviembre de 2018 da 19.924.349, pero al hacer la consulta completa el resultado para Noviembre 2018 es 34.854.349

alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que tenes que agregar parentisis nada más:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%c' ) AS fecha, SUM( COALESCE( grand_total, 0 )) as total 
FROM sma_sales 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') = '2018' 
AND (customer_id = 10 OR customer_id = 21 OR customer_id = 23 OR customer_id = 30 OR customer_id = 37) 
GROUP BY date_format( date, '%c' ) 
ORDER BY date_format( date, '%c' ) ASC
```

Tambien podría haberse escrito como:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%c' ) AS fecha, SUM( COALESCE( grand_total, 0 )) as total 
FROM sma_sales 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') = '2018' 
AND customer_id in (10 , 21, 23, 30, 37) 
GROUP BY date_format( date, '%c' ) 
ORDER BY date_format( date, '%c' ) ASC
```